# Execute query on each page load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to execute one query on page load. for that, I tried with the hooks in codeigniter. Here is the set up, I have done.

1. enable hooks in config `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;`
2. Added hook calling details in config/hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class'    => 'Global_executable',
    'function' => 'setSqlMode',
    'filename' => 'globalexecutable.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => ''
);
```

3. Here is my file globalexecutable.php from application\hooks directory.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

class Global_executable extends CI_Model {  
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setSqlMode() {  

        echo "All set to update sql mode.";  
    }  
}
```

Error that I'm getting is:

> Type: Error
> Message: Class 'CI_Model' not found
> Filename: \application\hooks\globalexecutable.php
> Line Number: 5
> Backtrace:
> File: \index.php Line: 318 Function: require_once

Can someone point the mistake please, I am beginner for CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CI Hooks you can able to call only controller, from controller call your modal and execute your query.
Change your code like `CI_Modal` to `CI_Controller`